# Change button shape onclick of button android

Tags: android

I want to change the button shape `onclick` something like this

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to site or give credits to owner of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

If you donot know about mockup, try learning android development with mockup

https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/examples/android_mockup_tool
or
https://www.invisionapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's Material Design effects that you can learn more using this [developer.android link.](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html)

Answer (score 0):

These are Material design animations, you can read more about material design in Android [here](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html) and design it yourself.

**OR**

Why re invent the wheel. If you're looking for animations like these, there are some libraries which can help you do that :

- check [FABRevealLayout](https://github.com/truizlop/FABRevealLayout)
- [FabTransitionActivity](https://github.com/coyarzun89/FabTransitionActivity)
- Other button animations : [Awesome button animations](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Button.md)